# Effect of tear gas and laughing gas together

Tags: toxicity

What will happen if someone uses tear gas, such as **CS** $(\ce{C10H5ClN2})$ and laughing gas, $\ce{N2O}$, in auditorium? Means will people start laughing and crying together? Or there will be other effect?

Comment: I think you should do some research on both classes of chemicals because their colloquial names don't tell the full story.  Reformulating this in terms of their pharmacology would be interesting, but right now it's based on a false premise.

Comment: This question is an interesting thought question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Admittedly, I had to smile when I first read your question.

Unfortunately, the effect for people exposed to both agents is not comparable to hearing a joke and a sad story at the same time. There is no cuteness in that.

Flooding an enclosed space with $\ce{N2O}$ is not a good idea! $\ce{N2O}$ is an interesting drug, used for sedation in dentistry. Here, a **mixture of $\ce{N2O}$
and oxygen** is fed to the patient through a nose mask, while the patient can freely exhale. Note that $\ce{N2O}$ apparently isn't metabolized, but just exhaled.

Feeding a heavier-than-air gas to a room without proper fresh air supply and circulation will lead to accumulation of this gas. Whether this could lead to (cerebral) hypoxia and permanent damages is open to calculation.

The use of **CS** in enclosed spaces is even worse. It is actually considered a chemical weapon, banned from war zones and only used in civil riot control. Oh, the irony! Note that it actually isn't a gas but a solid, dispersed either in solution or from granades. It is a strong irritant to all mucuous membranes and the skin.

Now imagine a densely packed auditorium full of people with burning sensation in their eyes and on their skin, crying, shouting, coughing, vomiting and running around in panic for an exit or relief and you know that this isn't the place to be!

Comment: +1. I never understood why CS is legal to use (and own in some countries) while being banned by the UN in war as a chemical weapon. Admittedly, I actually never understood war regulations at all...

Comment: @Jori, without CS in the hands of the militias who think of themselves as policemen, the mafias who construe the elaborate systems we live in would have no means to keep the few thousand people in each country who see through it all from putting them all in jail, and bringing the systems back to serving honest citizens.